# RedirectToAction with parameters in the path

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use RedirectToAction to redirect to one of the three actions below. However RedirectToAction is redirecting to /Move/Staging?userId=12345 which results in a 404. What I'm trying to do with the RedirectToAction is that it redirects to /Move/12345/Staging.

I'm using RedirectToAction as follows

```
return RedirectToAction("StagingMove", "Maintenance", new { userId = model.userId});
```

I've configured the Actions as followed.

```
    [HttpGet("Move/{userId?}/Staging/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StagingMove(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            {Snip}        
            return View(user );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.LogError(0, ex, "Move User Staging");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("Move/{userId?}/Arrival/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StagingArrival(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await this._userManager.GetUserAsync(userId);        
            return View(user );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.LogError(0, ex, "Move User Arrival");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("Move/{userId?}/Departures/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StagingDepartures(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await this._userManager.GetUserAsync(userId);        
            return View(user );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.LogError(0, ex, "Move User Departures");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I've looked into this and as far as I can tell it does work for when you have Move/Staging/{userId}. However, I can't get it to work in my situation with stuff behind the parameter.

Comment: Default Route Configuration is  {controller}/{action}/{id} where Id parameter is optional,  /Move/12345/Staging is means 12345 is the action method of Move Controller

Comment: @raju1208 so if I add an additional route that will fix it?

Comment: Hard to say what is going on here without more code. I don't see how it could be possible for your RedirectToAction which passed an object with a single property named userId to route to an action that takes a regId parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@King-king](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king) I got it working.

> attribute routing and convention-based routing are exclusively
> effective. In this case you use attribute routing so the path used in RedirectToAction won't work.

I modified my actions, for example:

```
[Route("Move/{userId?}/Staging/", Name = "MoveStaging")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StagingMove(string userId)
{
    try
    {
        {Snip}        
        return View(user );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this._logger.LogError(0, ex, "Move User Staging");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Now I can use RedirectToRoute.

```
return RedirectToRoute("MoveStaging", new { userId = model.userId});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not right. I use attribute routing all over the place while passing in the name of the underlying action in RedirectToAction. You've worked around some other problem in your code IMO.

Comment: @tnk479 not sure about what you've experienced but here is the quote in the Microsoft documentation `Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the conventional routes and vice-versa` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing  I really don't remember if there is a different behavior in the old MVC or not.

Comment: The first parameter of RedirectToAction is actionName. It doesn't make any difference what routing convention is used.

Comment: @tnk479 actually if you build the URL following conventional routing, it won't work. But the `RedirectToAction` does generate the link using the applied routing (so it will not generate the conventional url) and it does work.

Comment: I think you can try with `RedirectToAction` again, it should work because it generates the url correctly no matter the routing is based on convention or attribute. The url is generated according to the currently effective routing (so they are different in both cases).

Comment: My last assumption was wrong because I thought the `RedirectToAction` will always generate the url based on `conventional routing` (which won't work) but actually it generates the url based on the currently effective routing, so it should always work. Sorry about that.

Comment: RedirectToAction does not work where as RedirectToRoute does work.

Comment: RedirectToAction works just fine if you use it correctly. I have used it extensively across many apps. Trust me that it does in fact work fine in every version of .net core.